# It's too small. Put it bigger

Tags: grammar

I played the music song for him on computer.

The size of video was small.

> "It's too small. **Put it bigger**."

he said.

He wanted me to enlarge the size of video to bigger or full screen.

What the verb should use to enlarge video size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make** it bigger.

"*Put* it bigger" doesn't make any sense.  *Put* means "place", but you're not placing anything.

Comment: "put it on a larger size setting" would be sensible (even though it doesn't involve placing anything anywhere), but a lot more wordy than just "make it bigger".